# Google Chrome full screen video uses 1/4 of the screen

Tags: google-chrome

I have installed Version 80.0.3987.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu 19.10

Whenever I run full screen videos in Chrome, it uses a quarter of the screen, specifically the top left corner. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Same here, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: is flash plugin  (pepper/adobe) active?

Answer (score 2):

## Step 1

Click <kbd>Right Mouse Button</kbd> on Chrome title bar in the top and check
`☑ Use system title bar and borders`

## Step 2 (optional)

You can then then remove the title once again by deselecting `Show window Titles`. Works perfectly on Pop OS 20.04.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me as a workaround. The downside is that the Google Chrome window is constantly showing its top bar in non-fullscreen mode.

Comment: It works, but in my version this option is only available in Settings -> Appearance.

Comment: @Matt I found a fix for the top bar in non-fullscreen mode, check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Points you could try to get it fixed:

- Run Google Chrome in incognito mode and verify if the behavior the same
- Disable all extensions if previous point fixes wrong behavior, then enable extensions one-by-one checking what extension causes the issue
- Try different version of Google Chrome
- Reset Google Chrome settings to default
- Try to launch Google Chrome in different desktop environment: xubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-desktop, mate-desktop, budgie-desktop...
- Try to use [the next extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enhancer-for-youtube/ponfpcnoihfmfllpaingbgckeeldkhle/related):

[image]